# How to do vagrant up without login in the end?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a vagrant machine where I want to prevent ssh login to the machine after the boot. My system does not use any synced folder or I also do not have any provision script.

I tried these options

1. `config.ssh.timeout`  Apparently not supported
2. `config.vm.boot_timeout` In my case the boot time is unknown so if I use this I need to do a huge waiting. Also that throws an error when timeout happens which I do not want.

Any help?